# ColorSpectrum gives Unexpected Color when ColorChangeEvent occurs in uwp?

Tags: xaml, uwp

what i have tried is?

My XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <ColorSpectrum ColorChanged="ColorSpectrum_ColorChanged" Width="300" Height="300"></ColorSpectrum>
</Grid>
```

My C# Code:

```
    private void ColorSpectrum_ColorChanged(ColorSpectrum sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(args.NewColor + "   " + args.OldColor);
        Color cl = new Color();
        cl.A = 255;
        cl.R = 2;
        cl.G = 2;
        cl.B = 2;
        (sender as ColorSpectrum).Color = cl;
    }
```

I have a ColorSpectrum in my Xaml. When i change the color in the spectrum by clicking inside the spectrum,the ColorChangeEvent Occurs.During ColorChangeEvent ,i have Printed the new and old color.And then,I have set the colorSpectrum color by using Color Property in ColorSpectrum((sender as ColorSpectrum).Color = cl;)

when I first time click inside the spectrum(Clicking aproximately at the dark blue area) it gives output like this,

```
         Eg:  #FF0519FF   #FFFFFFFF
              #FF000002   #FF020202
```

Here **#FF0519FF**(blue color) is a new color where I'm click.

when I second time click inside the spectrum(Clicking aproximately at the same dark blue area) it gives output like this,

```
         Eg:  #FF000002   #FF020202
              #FF000002   #FF020202
```

Here **#FF000002**(Not a blue color(Why??)) is a color which has been given as new color, but I click at Dark Blue area.This gives Unexpected output.I Don't know what's happening here?

What's the real working of Color Property in ColorSpectrum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an expected behavior, when you set the cl as the Color of ColorSpectrum, the ARGB you set made the Hue-Saturation-Value Black, so the color you choose later will be displayed with such saturation, that is Black. If you want the ColorChanged event to work normally, you could change the Color you set for the ColorSpectrum. Make sure at least one value in RGB is 255, then its saturation will be 100%. For example:

```
Color cl = new Color();
cl.A = 255;
cl.R = 255;
cl.G = 2;
cl.B = 2;
(sender as ColorSpectrum).Color = cl;
```

Comment: Thank you.. I agree your point...I want to set the the color of colorSpectrum(i.e.,I want to change the position of selection mark(circle inside colorspectrum(selected color))) according to the corresponding color given by me..I will give a color,for that i want to change the circle corresponding position.How to do that?

Comment: ,Did you find anything?

Comment: Do you mean when you click inside the spectrum, you want the circle in the spectrum to appear where you clicked?

Comment: No.I mean ,for my case I'll give a color(#FFF5F5F5 for example) .For this color ,I want to set circle Position Corresponding to this color given.

Comment: When you give a color to the ColorSpectrum, the circle inside the ColorSpectrum can't display in the corresponding color area? When I set a color to the ColorSpectrum.Color, the circle displayed well.

Comment: yaeh.But if i set color like #FF020202 ,the spectrum color also changed.Now i click inside the spectrum it gives wrong color?that was the prblem.how to solve this issue?

Comment: As I mentioned, when you set the color as #FF020202, the Hue-Saturation-Value will become Black, so the color you choose later will be displayed with such saturation, it will always return Black. It is by design. If you want to fix it, **you could make sure at least one value in RGB is 255, as the code above**. The HSV you can refer to ColorPicker, the slider below color spectrum, when you set the color for the ColorPicker, the slider will slide to the black part, the same behavior as this ColorSpectrum. The slider from ColorPicker controls the hsv, but the ColorSpectrum can't control it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215806/discussion-between-premkumar-shanmugam-and-faywang-msft).